# Retract (change) poll vote

Tags: discussion, support

Is it possible? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not, you get:

[You are only allowed to vote 1 time in this poll http://mrozekma.com/so-poll-one-time.png](http://mrozekma.com/so-poll-one-time.png)

You can post a feature request on the [main meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and it might be changed

Answer (score 0):

the question was: "Why not?" which there seems to be hesitance to answer this. If people could retract votes, which technically is possible, they could have themselves represented better, but they may not know best themselves.

Comment: This question was about polls, which are no longer available on SE. Other votes and flags on SE can be retracted, with some limitations — for example an upvote or downvote on a question or answer is “locked in” after a few hours, and can only be reversed if the post is edited.